# Create multiple columns from existing Hive table columns

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql

How to create multiple columns from an existing hive table. The example data would be like below.

[image]

My requirement is to create 2 new columns from existing table only when the condition met.
col1 when code=1. col2 when code=2.

expected output:

[image]

Please help in how to achieve it in Hive queries?

Comment: Does final table doesnt have any relation between col1 and col2. I mean you can use this sql but this will make nulls too. `select 
case when code=1 then col end as col1,
case when code=2 then col end as col2
from table`

Comment: HI @Koushik Roy , there is no relation between the columns in my case. How these NULL values present in result set. Is there any better possible way please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aggregate values required into arrays, then you can explode and filter only those with matching positions.

Demo:

```
with 

my_table as (--use your table instead of this CTE
select stack(8,
'a',1,
'b',2,
'c',3,
'b1',2,
'd',4,
'c1',3,
'a1',1,
'd1',4
) as (col, code)
)

select c1.val as col1, c2.val as col2 from
(
select collect_set(case when code=1 then col else null end) as col1,
       collect_set(case when code=2 then col else null end) as col2 
  from my_table where code in (1,2)
)s lateral view outer posexplode(col1) c1 as pos, val  
   lateral view outer posexplode(col2) c2 as pos, val
where c1.pos=c2.pos
```

Result:

```
col1    col2
a       b
a1      b1
```

This approach will not work if arrays are of different size.

Another approach - calculate row_number and full join on row_number, this will work if col1 and col2 have different number of values (some values will be null):

```
with 

my_table as (--use your table instead of this CTE
select stack(8,
'a',1,
'b',2,
'c',3,
'b1',2,
'd',4,
'c1',3,
'a1',1,
'd1',4
) as (col, code)
),

ordered as
(
select code, col, row_number() over(partition by code order by col) rn
  from my_table where code in (1,2)
)

select c1.col as col1, c2.col as col2
  from (select * from ordered where code=1) c1 
       full join 
       (select * from ordered where code=2) c2 on c1.rn = c2.rn
```

Result:

```
col1    col2
a       b
a1      b1
```

Comment: Hi @leftjoin , Thanks for the solutions. Is it possible to give independent query (approach 2) because you have suggested the query along with my_table.

Comment: @Rajasekhar888 instead of  my_table use your real table. Just remove my_table from WITH and replace MY_TABLE with your table name